# Using REST to fetch SharePoint View Items

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to construct the correct URL to return the items in a SharePoint View using the REST api.

Using my browser and the following URL I can return the items in the list.

```
https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/Items
```

And I can get the view definition using the following URL.

```
https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/Views/getbytitle('Latest News')/
```

But I cannot figure out what I need to put at the end of that URL to actually get the items that are returned by the the View.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[SP.View object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245986(v=office.15).aspx) does **not** contain any methods for manipulating list items. But [SP.View object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245986(v=office.15).aspx) contains [SP.View.viewQuery property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247163(v=office.15).aspx) that specifies the query that is used by the list view. That means the following approach could be used for retrieving list items for view:

- perform the first request to get CAML Query for List View using [SP.View.viewQuery property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247163(v=office.15).aspx)
- perform the second request to retrieve List Items by specifying CAML Query

### How to return list items for a List View using REST API using JavaScript

```
function getJson(url) 
{
    return $.ajax({       
       url: url,   
       type: "GET",  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    });
}


function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}


function getListItemsForView(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle)
{
     var viewQueryUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')/ViewQuery";
     return getJson(viewQueryUrl).then(
         function(data){         
             var viewQuery = data.d.ViewQuery;
             return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewQuery); 
         });
}
```

**Usage**

```
getListItemsForView(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Announcements','Latest News')
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.  As an aside does anyone know why there isn't a method to return the items in a View?  It seems  very odd that the API expects the developer to construct and execute the query.

Comment: @Vadim, This is awesome answer. But, is it possible to retrieve only visible fields for that view. Because above code will retrieve so many fields which are not really required. Ideally I don't want to pass the field name as `items[i].Title` . Is there such possibility?

Comment: @Mihir, that's doable i believe via `SP.View.viewFields property` which returns  `Gets a value that specifies the collection of fields in the list view.`