# How can I get list items by view name, using REST API ajax?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-rest-api

I tried to get a list of items from the Sharepoint library by view name. I had ajax rest API URL:

```
url: webapp + "_api/web/list/getbytitle" + "('" + LibraryName + "')/View/getbytitle" +"('" + viewName + "')"
method:"GET"
header:"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose
```

How can I get all the items in view name?

Answer (score 0):

please refer the following code snippet to get items from specific view, Rest API not provider items endpoint return from a view directly.
So please do the following:

1. perform the first request to get CAML Query for List View using SP.View.viewQuery property
2. perform the second request to retrieve List Items by specifying CAML Query:

   ```
       getListItemsForView(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'MyList12','View1')
       .done(function(data)
       {
            var items = data.d.results;
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
                console.log(items[i].Title);
            }    
       })
       .fail(
       function(error){
           console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
       });



    function getListItemsForView(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle)
       {
            var viewQueryUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')/ViewQuery";
            return getJson(viewQueryUrl).then(
                function(data){         
                    var viewQuery = data.d.ViewQuery;
                    return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewQuery); 
                });
       }

       function getJson(url) 
       {
           return $.ajax({       
              url: url,   
              type: "GET",  
              contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
              headers: { 
                 "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
              }
           });
       }



    function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
       {
           var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
           var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
           var queryPayload = {  
                      'query' : {
                             '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                             'ViewXml' : viewXml  
                      }
           };

           return $.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  method: "POST",
                  data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
                  headers: {
                     "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                     "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                     "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                  }
            });
       }
   ```

Same question has been answered here:

[Using REST to fetch SharePoint View Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884647/using-rest-to-fetch-sharepoint-view-items)