# SharePoint API using MS Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

URL = https://uk.sharepoint.com/sites/CKnowledge/Guard/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I can **GET** this URL on MS Graph using:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/uk.sharepoint.com:/sites/CKnowledge:/lists/%7B00000000-0000--0000-0000-000000000000%7D

But I can't seem to **GET** this URL on MS Graph:

https://uk.sharepoint.com/sites/CKnowledge/Guard/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=848cf2f9-0ece-4f16-a9e9-fbdef773655c

Comment: Does this view have any filtering in it? If so, you would have to recreate the same $filter in your Graph API call when using the list drive items method. Alternatively, you could look into using the older REST API endpoints. It should be possible to use a CAML query/xml for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884647/using-rest-to-fetch-sharepoint-view-items

Answer (score 1):

Please try follow below 2 steps to get items in a document library or list:

1. Using `/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children` or
   `/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items` to get the item id of the target folder, file or list.
2. Get the target content by `/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}`  or `/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}`

Hope this helps. Best Wishes.

Answer (score 0):

### Getting all List items

In MS Graph I think it is not possible to Enumerate items within a list view. So you need to rewrite the filter clause by yourself to get the same result than your view

For further reference you can read the official Graph Documentation, it does not mention list view:

[Enumerate items in a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

So basically you need to start by getting all items with

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
```

I let you search where you can find site-id and list-id as it is very easy.

### Filtering all items with filter clause

Next you need to build your filter clause according your view parameters.
Here is the documentation, the last part is especially usefull for starting:

[Use the filter query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Filter clause is not very easy at first and there is some limitation especially with related lists, but you can do something like this:

To get items WHERE myValue equal 'Member':

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items$filter=myValue eq 'Member'
```

To get items WHERE 'myValue' is not null:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items$filter=myValue ne null
```

To get items WHERE 'mail' equal 'mail1@domain.com' OR 'mail2@domain.com':

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items$filter=mail in ('mail1@domain.com', 'mail2@domain.com')
```

The filter part of the API request use the column internal name. To get the internal name the simple way is to open this column settings into Sharepoint UI and look at page URL. You will find the column name into it.

---

**NOTE for non latin alphabet language:**

Sharepoint UI does not allow to set internal name and display name separatly, so most of users when creating column, choose the column name as they want the name appear on the list, Sharepoint will take this name and clean it to create an internal name.

So not latin char will be URL-Encoded and if the column column name contains only not latin char, the internal name will become an URL-Encoded string like (%FF%FF%FF%FF) which is very painefull for code reading.

So when you create a column with Sharepoint UI you should first create the column with latin alphabet then edit your column name according your language as edition will only modify the display name, not the internal name. On Sharepoint Online it is not possible to change the internal name afterward.